# API for check spelling in Android

Tags: android, nlp

I'm learning about natural language processing, and are required to make a project.
I'm trying to build an application that checks spelling for Vietnamese. However, I just stopped in putting data into the software. I do not know how to split the input data and how to write the code to checks spelling.
I know, Android have APIs support this. Who can recommend me an API and how to use it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html?

Comment: I need to check spelling for the entire document to be put into a file from .txt. Not that the input from the user. It can do this?

Comment: it works for any text.  You'll still need to display a UI for the user to make changes.

Comment: wow, it supports multi-language support or only English?

Comment: it is not support for vietnamese :(